VB.Net application connect to SQL Azure Instance with MFA
I have a VB.NET application that has 2 routines to open databases in SQL which all worked fine until we migrated databases to an SQL Azure Instance with MFA.
The first sequence works fine with MFA and gets authenticated to show the list of databases to choose from. However, when i pick the database from the selection in the application, i cannot get the MFA prompt to authenticate again
Any help appreciated
Private connection2 As SqlConnection
    Private Sub ImageComboBoxDatabase_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ImageComboBoxDatabase.SelectedIndexChanged

        TreeList1.Visible = False
        WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()

        Dim listDataBases As New List(Of String)()
        server = ImageComboBoxDatabase.EditValue.ToString
        Dim connectString As String = "Data Source=" & server & " ; Authentication=Active Directory Interactive; Encrypt=True; Initial Catalog=master; User Id=" & User


        connection2 = New SqlConnection(connectString) ' Store the connection
        connection2.Open()

        Dim selectSQL As String = "Select name from sys.databases where name Like 'cw_%';"

        'Using con As New SqlConnection(connectString)

        Using com As New SqlCommand(selectSQL, connection2)
            Using dr As SqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()
                While dr.Read()
                    listDataBases.Add(dr(0).ToString())
                End While
            End Using
        End Using

        GridLookUpEditDropDown.Properties.DataSource = listDataBases        
    End Sub

Public Cnstring As String
Private connection As New SqlConnection(Cnstring)

Private Sub SimpleButtonProjectSwitch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SimpleButtonProjectSwitch.Click
          
          
            CnString = "Data Source=" & server & " ; Authentication=Active Directory Interactive; Encrypt=True; Initial Catalog=master; User Id=" & UserNameVariable
            
            'Treelist
            TreeListTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = Cnstring
Me.TreeListTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Ds_TreeList.TreeList)
    End Sub

I can get it to work if i use an SQL Login username but not an authenticated user which i need

How do i keep the first connection open and use it for the second routine ?

You mean to say you want to use MFA for first time assignment and then it should not ask for login or MFA again?

Yes, i'd like the first connection to continue

Do i need to get an Access token ?

No. You just need to use the same  connection again instead of  defining a new connection.

Can you give me an example? The user gets the list of databases and then selects one but it fails to load the treeadapter fill as it says login failed for user

all help appreciated

Could you share your project in github repo

Yes, i'll upload now

https://github.com/sullman1/Sullman1Test

any luck with looking at it ?

I tried, unfortunately, I  am getting issue with Devexpress as I don't have subscription for Devexpress.Data. Desktop

anybody can share a light ?
